# Editing controls embedded in custom control (C#, WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I have a custom (composed) component (GridEX in ToolStripContainer with some specialised ToolStripPanels) and I would like to have the ability to change the GridEX when I place this custom component on some form, but when I do, it behaves as a one piece (which is superb), but no custom editors are accessible -> therefore I can not modify the columns etc.

It is possible to enable such editing capabilities on this custom component?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, it is... and there is not enough "thank you"-s I can write you here... and I was honestly searching for the answer for the last 2 hours here on S/O to be sure, it is not a duplicate... still... thank you.

Comment: Side note: try to avoid adding extra [thank you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) to your posts even if you want to add many.